# Why does ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Count() return different results on immediately subsequent calls?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Consider the following:

```
        IEnumerable<ShellTile> pinnedtiles = ShellTile.ActiveTiles;
        Console.WriteLine(pinnedtiles.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(pinnedtiles.Count());
```

Assuming you have more than 0 ActiveTiles, the first call to Count() will return the correct value, but the second call will return 0.

If you dont set ShellTile.ActiveTiles to a local variable, it works fine. I assume this is because ActiveTiles is actually an instance of the internal class ShellTileEnumerator and for some reason, when accessed via the IEnumerable interface, it is acting like a forward-only enumerator. Seems like a likely 'gotcha', or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right

```
  MessageBox.Show(ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Count().ToString());
  MessageBox.Show(ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Count().ToString());
```

The above one will work but not when you assign to IEnumeable .... :)

Another easy way is to assign it toa  List instead of IEnumerable . This works too

```
 List<ShellTile> pinnedtiles = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.ToList(); ;
 MessageBox.Show(pinnedtiles.Count().ToString());
 MessageBox.Show(pinnedtiles.Count().ToString());
```